# Abstract class error in Java with Comparable<T>

Tags: java, abstract-class

I don't know of this error and how to fix it. I'm getting this error with all of my child classes. Included the Error Message and the abstract method that needs to be over written. Added class and what is inside of class.

Error:

```
MyMath3 is not abstract and does not overide abstract method compareTo(Homework3) in java.lang.Compareable
```

Code:

```
public abstract class Homework3 implements Comparable<Homework3> 


public class MyMath3 extends Homework3 


private int page;
    private String typeHomework;



    /**

     * Constructor for objects of class MyMath

     */

    public MyMath3(int p)

    {

    }   
    public void createAssignment(int p)

    {
        typeHomework="Math";
        page=p;
    }

    public String getHomework() 

    {

        return typeHomework;

    }

    public int getPage()

    {

        return page;

    }

    public String toString()

    {

        return typeHomework+"--- The number of pages needed to read:"+page;
    }

} 


public int compareTo(Homework3 obj,Homework3 obj2 )
    {
        int compareResult= obj.compareTo(obj2);
        return compareResult;
    }
```

Comment: mouse-over the error message in eclipse and click "implement all abstract methods" option

Comment: In the future, please use copy-and-paste, rather than re-typing and manually introducing mistakes that were not present in the source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signature of your `compareTo` method should be:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(final Homework3 other)
```

You can access your current object using... `this`!

---

By the way, you might run into some `StackOverflowException` in a few minutes/seconds...
That's because your `compareTo` method recursively calls itself. You probably meant to compare the number of pages needed to be read. If so, this could be the body of your `compareTo` implementation:

```
return this.getPage() - other.getPage();
```

Cheers ;)